# Построение таблиц базы данных

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Какой должна быть структура таблиц, чтобы можно было задать к одному товару несколько категорий, так как это сделано на stackoverflow?

[image: У одного вопроса несколько тегов]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

колонка categories с массивом цифр id категорий куда попадает товар

Comment: А потом захочется посчитать количество товаров в категории - и приплыли. Быстро это работать не сможет.

Comment: О, я обожаю писать SQL. В тегах указан mysql. Как вы будете искать? like? find_in_set? Быстро такое работать не будет, это гарантированный fullscan.

Answer (score 5):

Таблица связей с двумя колонками — `itemId`, `categoryId`. Другие варианты чреваты проблемами.